# Error while compiling monodevelop 7.6 on Archlinux

Tags: c#, makefile, mono, monodevelop, archlinux

I'm trying to install monodevelop from package on AUR but no luck. So I tried to compile it from the source code on github.

I followed the [mono compiling tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/) and installed `mono 5.4.1` (a parallel one on /opt/mono, so is other dependencies in the page) and `msbuild 15`(from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/msbuild-stable/))

When I enter the enviroment and compile the code

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono --profile=stable
make
sudo make install
```

Everything went on fine while doing `./configure` but when building I got errors like

```
Mono.Addins.Setup/AddinPackage.cs(39,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICSharpCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins.Setup/Mono.Addins.Setup.csproj]
Mono.Addins.Setup/AddinStore.cs(41,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICSharpCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins.Setup/Mono.Addins.Setup.csproj]
Mono.Addins.Setup/SetupService.cs(37,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICSharpCode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins.Setup/Mono.Addins.Setup.csproj]
```

and

```
/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/external/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c(36,3): error G08E93E1A: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘BIO {aka struct bio_st}’ [/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.csproj]
/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/external/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c(94,1): error GC2E79D46: variable ‘git_stream_bio_method’ has initializer but incomplete type [/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.csproj]
/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/external/libgit2/src/openssl_stream.c(94,19): error GC0CDC97E: storage size of ‘git_stream_bio_method’ isn’t known [/home/jeff2310/tmp/monodevelop/main/src/addins/VersionControl/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git/MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.csproj]
```

All the errors are here

https://pastebin.com/fbGPMKTx

It's the same error as the AUR package failed. If anyone know how to do please tell me.